# Recursive CTE: Parent Child relation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is there a way that I use recursive function  but without going to the end of the tree?
For example:

Assume I have a simple tree like below

For each Node, I want to look to the already computed score underneath the current node, and use it in its current weight

```
Node Score = (Current Kr)* (Current Weight) + (Next Node Already Computed Score) *(Next Node Weight)
              -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                        CurrentWeight + Next Node Weight
```

[image]

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE TreeTable(
   Teamid           INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,ParentId         INTEGER 
  ,Name             VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,ParentName       VARCHAR(255)
  ,TeamRollupType             VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL
  ,KR INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,TeamWeight INTEGER NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO TreeTable(Teamid,ParentId,Name,ParentName,TeamRollupType,KR,TeamWeight) VALUES (1,NULL,'Team1',NULL,'Current and Child',70,8);
INSERT INTO TreeTable(Teamid,ParentId,Name,ParentName,TeamRollupType,KR,TeamWeight) VALUES (2,1,'Team1A','Team1','Current and Child',98,1);
INSERT INTO TreeTable(Teamid,ParentId,Name,ParentName,TeamRollupType,KR,TeamWeight) VALUES (3,2,'Team1B','Team1A','Current and Child',26,5);


select * from TreeTable;
```

TreeTable Result :

[image]

Attempt: Code I am doing is going down till last node

```
 with rcte as
(
  select 
         t.TeamID as GroupID,
         t.Name as GroupName,
         t.TeamRollupType as GroupType,
         t.TeamId,
         t.Name,
         t.TeamRollupType,
         --Value
         case t.TeamRollupType
           when 'Child List' then 0 
           when 'ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0 -- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           else t.KR
         end as Value,
         --Weight
         case t.TeamRollupType
           when 'Child List' then 0 
           when 'ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0-- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           else t.TeamWeight
         end as WeightValue,

         --Value*Weight
         WeightedScore=
         case t.TeamRollupType
           when 'Child List' then 0 
           when 'ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0-- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           else t.KR
         end 
         *
         case t.TeamRollupType
           when 'Child List' then 0
           when 'ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0-- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           else t.TeamWeight
         end 
        

  from  treetable t
union all
  select 
         r.GroupID,
         r.GroupName,
         r.GroupType,
         t.TeamId,
         t.Name,
         --TeamRollupType
         case r.TeamRollupType
           when 'Current List' then 'Current List' -- if the parent was the end of the sum, then it stays the end of the sum
           else t.TeamRollupType
         end,
         --Value
         case
           when r.TeamRollupType = 'Current List' then 0 -- if the parent was the end of the sum, then the current value changes to 0
           when t.TeamRollupType = 'Child List' then 0 
           when t.TeamRollupType ='ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0-- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           else t.KR
         end,
         --TeamWeight
         case
           when r.TeamRollupType = 'Current List' then 0 -- if the parent was the end of the sum, then the current value changes to 0
           when t.TeamRollupType = 'Child List' then 0 -- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           when t.TeamRollupType ='ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0
           else t.TeamWeight
         end,

         --Teamweight*Value
         case
           when r.TeamRollupType = 'Current List' then 0 -- if the parent was the end of the sum, then the current value changes to 0
           when t.TeamRollupType = 'Child List' then 0 -- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           when t.TeamRollupType ='ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0
           else t.KR

         end 
         *
         case
           when r.TeamRollupType = 'Current List' then 0 -- if the parent was the end of the sum, then the current value changes to 0
           when t.TeamRollupType = 'Child List' then 0 -- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           when t.TeamRollupType ='ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0
           else t.TeamWeight
         end

  from rcte r
  join treetable t
    on t.ParentId = r.TeamId 
)
select r.GroupName,
       sum(r.weightedScore)/SUM(CASE When r.Value <> 0 Then r.WeightValue Else 0 End ) as GroupScore,
       string_agg(case when r.Value <> 0 then convert(nvarchar(255), r.Value) end, '+') as GroupSumFormula,
       string_agg(case when r.Value <> 0 then convert(nvarchar(255), r.Name) end, '+') as GroupSumTeam,
       string_agg(case when r.Value <> 0 then convert(nvarchar(255), r.WeightValue) end, '+') as GroupSumWeight
       --string_agg(case when r.Value <> 0 then convert(nvarchar(255), r.weightedScore) end, '+') as GroupSumrweightedScore,
    --   sum(r.Value) as GroupSum,
       --SUM(CASE When r.Value <> 0 Then r.WeightValue Else 0 End ) as TotalWeight,
       --sum(r.weightedScore) as GroupWeightedSum
       

from rcte r
group by r.GroupName
order by r.GroupName;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can TeamRollupType change along a tree? Or does the rolluptype of a root (ParentId NULL) determine the rolluptype of the whole tree?

Comment: The _anchor_ (aka first `select`) in your CTE has no `where` clause. That's unusual. Try starting from the bottom of the tree, i.e. nodes that have no children, and working your way "up" to the root.

Comment: `select ... from TreeTable as T where not exists ( select 42 from TreeTable as TChild where TChild.ParentId = T.TeamId` will start you at the leaves, i.e. nodes without children. `select ... from TreeTable as TParent inner join RCTE on RCTE.ParentId = TParent.TeamId` will take you up one level recursively.